# There a repository for Eclipse project jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

There's a project within the Eclipse Foundation, DevTools, which holds a sub-project, SqlTools, which contains a few libraries related to parsing SQL. I'd like to be able to link those libraries to my own project. I just can't for the life of me figure out the right terms to Google to find some repository for those jars.

I've found the source code alright and cloned the git repository but that's source code. I'd like to avoid hosting not only my own project's jars but any dependency it might have. Anyone know where to get these? Already reached out to the mailing list but am impatient. I've finally got free time to hack on the weekend for my own interests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jars are published in a [p2 repository](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_overview.htm).  http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates

A content.jar file describes the repo, and the actual jars are in http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/plugins

There is a nexus instance at http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/index.html that contains some sqltools jars, but publishing jars to maven.eclipse.org is still under construction.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one - http://search.maven.org/#browse

Better look. Clean, slick and more user friendly :)

Answer (score 1):

I use mvnrepository.com to search for libraries.

http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=Eclipse

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. Checked here and magenta central first. Am thinking this might just be one of those times where there is no good answer.

Comment: No worries. Very  much a " just in case " suggestion.